# For loop to compute multiple reactive variables

Tags: r, shiny

How do I set up a for loop which updates multiple reactive values every time the user changes the input value?

For example the program should read a raw file. Then based on the length of the raw file runs the for loop multiple times and each time update either of the counters we have based on an if statement. 
Everytime that the user updates the input value, the counters should be updated accordingly.

Below I tried to translate what I have in mind in a simplified format.

Thanks guys

```
my_data <- read.csv("whatever_raw_file.csv")
counter_A <- 0
counter_B <- 0

for (i in 1:length(my_data)) {
  if (my_data[i] > user_input_value) {
    counter_A <- reactive({
      counter_A <- counter_A + 1
      counter_A
      })
  }
  else {
    counter_B <- reactive({
      counter_B <- counter_B + 1
      counter_B
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reactiveValues` instead.

Something like:

```
my_data <- read.csv("whatever_raw_file.csv")
counter <- reactiveValues( A = 0, B = 0)

# inside some reactive expression
for (i in 1:length(my_data)) {
  if (my_data[i] > user_input_value) {
    counter$A <- isolate(counter$A) + 1
  } else {
    counter$B <- isolate(counter$B) + 1
  }
}
```